# Extracting result of regression function in R script

Tags: r, linear-regression, rscript

In R Script, for instance in usage of;

```
regression=lm(a~b)
```

As known, result of linear model regression can be summarized by

```
summarize(regression)
```

In this sample regression variable is a vector which have sub variables an it can be retrieve calling regression['subvariable name'] or regression[subvar number].

I couldn't retrieve the p-value of this model. It's shown in summary output but it couldn't
extract from vector.

Calling in names() function breaks down subvariables but some of subvariable have nested values. So i couldn't find them one by one.

Is there any way?

Comment: `summary(lm(a~b))$coefficients[, 4]` Or you call the column explicitly by `summary(lm(a~b))$coefficients[, "Pr(>|t|)"]`

Comment: Very thanks Mr. Arenburg, it works nicely but throws titles even i call summary(lm(a~b))$coefficients[, 4][1]. But i need only numeric value.

Comment: `unname(summary(lm(a~b))$coefficients[, 4])` or `as.numeric(summary(lm(a~b))$coefficients[, 4])`

Comment: It works. Thanks again. R is immense.

Comment: NP. Welcome to [tag:r]. Enjoy your stay :)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).